# Don't switch to monitor speakers when plugging in to laptop

Tags: windows-10

How can I prevent my laptop to switch to monitor speakers whenever I plug in an HDMI monitor?

At work we have flex desks. I plug in to various monitors over the work week.
I never want any monitor to add their speakers or microphone to my list of input and output devices. Definitely not set them as current default. They require me to fumble around with EarTrumpet every time I start a conference call.

Is there a way in windows 10 to not automatically recognize speakers and assigning them as default when plugging in a monitor's HDMI cable?

Comment: For future readers, the question marked as duplicate is indeed what I'm looking for and the answer is: there's no straight forward way.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try:
open control panel -> go to "Hardware and Sound" -> Click "Sound" -> playback tab
you should see
[image]

- you can try to set the device you want to stick as default by right clicking on it and clicking "Set as Default Device"
- another option if the above doesn't work is to disable outputs sound to device by right clicking on output device you don't want to work and click "Disable"

Comment: Sadly new devices appear to get priority over configured preferences so every time you plug in a new monitor you have to go set this.